# printf struct from binary file to screen

Tags: c

i am currently struggling about couldn't output(printf) or correctly read the binary.

> The following code resulted as (fread: Success) though.

```
if (fread(list, sizeof(struct Ticket), 10, fp) == 10){
    perror("fread");
}
```

then i try to printf with the following code:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    printf("%d\t%s\t%d\n", list[i].code, list[i].station, list[i].price);
}
```

Resulted messy unidentify code(although it was 10 line).

also, when i try to go forward with following code:

```
printf("\nPlease submit your destination\n");
scanf("%d\n", dec);

fprintf(stdout, "%d\t%s\t%d\n", list[dec-1].code, list[dec-1].station, list[dec-1].price);
```

Error appeared as Segmentation violation after input at scanf.

P.S. The fwrite was tested with perror("fwrite");
     and resulted success.

Sorry for poor english and programming.
would really appreciate if anyone could help.

Thanks

Comment: The `scanf` line should be `scanf("%d\n", &dec);`. How is `list` declared?

Comment: The list has 10 array contained
struct Ticket{

    int code;

    char *station;

    int price;

};

Comment: You could at least **pretend** this not the same question you asked yesterday *twice.* Change the struct name from `Ticket` to something else so the dupe is not immediately obvious... >.<

Comment: Thanks for your kindly suggestion
but i do not think this is the same question
coz the problem is different although the subject is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print formatted output,use `fscanf` instead of fread.

`fscanf()` is used for reading from text files (i.e. readable by humans)

`fread` is used for reading from binary files (i.e. in formats used
   by computers internally).

And you are getting segmentation violation since you have written scanf in wrong way.It should be

> scanf("%d\n", &dec);

You are printing output on screen using format specifiers.Then you should read your data using format specifier.No doubt you can read any file using `fread` 
You can read use of fread [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/fread.html)

Comment: sorry, didn't mention it has to be binary file.